# how to get get sign up message from my database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting up the wholly organized sign up form, I'm trying to sent into information into my MySQL database server. My code not work and can't figuring out pops up message You have been signed up!
I've tried several options but none of them work on a server,

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) or array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {
    // So I'm guessing here need to some additions of based my own inclinatios.
```

my code

```
<?php
    if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) or array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8955440_bigebro", "sunshine1987**", "id8955440_bigebro");
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die("There was an error connecting to the database");
        }
        if ($_POST['email'] == '') {
            echo "<p>Email address is required.</p>";
        } else if ($_POST['password'] == '') {
            echo "<p>Password is required.</p>";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `bigebro` WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                echo "<p>That email address has already been taken.</p>";
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `bigebro` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']) . "')";
                if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                    echo "<p>You have been signed up!";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>There was a problem signing you up - please try again later.</p>";
                }
            }
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>
```

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8955440_bigebro", "sunshine1987**", "id8955440_bigebro");

When I signed up form only pops up "There was a problem signing you up - please try again later" I want to expect to "you have been signed up" from the result
. [please see sign up form](https://bigebro.000webhostapp.com/7-mysql/)

Comment: You shouldn't store people's passwords in plain text

Comment: It means that you have a problem in your insert query

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_error` to track error in query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `bigebro` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']) . "')";
            if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                echo "<p>You have been signed up!";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
```

Also check your db stucture like id should be auto incremented, email and password should be varchar.
[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work as a message  "you have been signed up! ", I don't know whether a problem is my code or database.

Comment: @Bilguunenkhee, I have asked by using this you can track your error of mysql server. Use this and give me the error message.

Comment: No error message returned. I'm seeing error displays empty.

Comment: I have check at my end and this is working for me. So something wrong in your db structure. Share your db structure so I can check that for error.

Answer (score 0):

you should validate email and password with javascript.
put an echo statement below the line

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `bigebro` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']) . "')";

echo $query;
                if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                    echo "<p>You have been signed up!";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>There was a problem signing you up - please try again later.</p>";
                }
```

Run the printed query with the same database credentials. If it runs then the problem is with ur PHP code. u should have INSERT privileges for your database user.